# SublimeText3 + pandown + pandoc: includes_paths not working

Tags: sublimetext3, pandoc

I'm using ST3+pandown+pandoc to convert markdown to PDF. I want to use pandown's includes_paths setting to avoid typing the path to my image directory every time. I haven't been able to get it to work, however. Here's a MWE:

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
text.markdown
test/img.pdf
```

In text.markdown, I have:

```
![](img.pdf)
```

I've got set includes_paths as follows in `Pandown.sublime-settings`:

```
"includes_paths":
    [
        "test/"
    ],
```

But, no dice. I've also tried with an absolute path, `./test`, and `test`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Pandown](https://github.com/phyllisstein/Pandown)'s `includes_paths` only applies to Pandoc's `--include-in-header`, `--include-before-body` and `--include-after-body` [options](http://pandoc.org/README.html#general-writer-options), not image locations etc.

From [Pandown.sublime-settings](https://github.com/phyllisstein/Pandown/blob/master/Pandown.sublime-settings#L19) about `includes_paths`:

> Pandoc apparently doesn't search for values for its --include
>   arguments anywhere but the working directory, which makes
>   working from a standard stylesheet or standard script
>   sort of tedious.

Comment: Thanks, this is sensible. I'll post another answer with a workaround for other users who run into this.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, using the `graphicx` package loaded in the YAML header and `\graphicspath`:

```
---
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{graphicx}
---
\graphicspath{{test/}}

![](img.pdf)
```

Pandoc will say that it can't find img.pdf, but the image will be present in the final pdf.

Comment: You could also write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) that prepends `test/` to all image paths...